# iOS8/Swift strange null behaviour with response from REST service

Tags: ios, rest, swift, alamofire

Throughout my project I can perfectly check Alamofire responses and data for

```
if fooData != nil {
//do stuff
}
```

somehow in this instance Swift seems to have problems checking what the actual incoming type is

what I get if I print it is

```
<null>
```

what is this supposed to be? An array of null? Casts to NSDictionary or NSArray both fail.

The Rest response is the same as always throughout the project where I will potentially receive a null value and it gets catched everywhere else.

€dit with more code:
my request:

```
       Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(CurrentConfiguration.serverURL)/api/users/\(CurrentConfiguration.currentUser.id)/friends/\(targetUser)",encoding:.JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON {(request, response, friendData, error) in

    if friendData != nil {
     println(friendData!)

     //this is where the app obviously crashes as there is nothing inside of "friendData"
     let resp = friendData as NSDictionary 


    //load friendData into the UI
    }

}
```

the print statement gives me the above mentioned null representation, but obviously does not recognize  as nil

the response from the node backend comes as

```
index.sendJsonResponse(res, 200, null);
```

Comment: could you post your actual code?

Comment: I agree, this will be difficult to help with if you don't have code.

Comment: edited first post with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in Playground:

```
let fooData:AnyObject = NSNull()
println(fooData)
```

It prints `<null>`.

`fooData` is not `nil`, but a instance of [`NSNull`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/index.html)

Comment: thanks - guess i will be just checking for "if friendData is NSNull" then

Comment: To add a little info, this happens when the JSON includes a null value ('null')

Comment: so what would be the correct null response? responding like i pasted above seems to work out perfectly fine for the angular frontend as well as for the android app - checking for "== null"